# how to yank out a field from a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

i'am trying to pull out a field from file and write the extracted field into a new file, could anybody please help me with this. i have the data in the file like below

```
"","Processed","XXXXXX XX XXXX XXXX","Import","hgjgf XXXXXXXXXXX                LTD","XXX","sss,ggg.00","0x/xx/xxxx","Xrrrr XXXXXXXX","","XTH asdf XX XXXXXX
XXX000XXX
XXXXXX XXX OCEAN                                                                                           fsdgdhfjgh","WXXXXX","000XXX","X0ASDFXXX","XX","","","","X","","","X","","",""
```

Comment: what exactly do you want extracted from that?

Comment: say..i wanted to extract field no 4,6 and 8. The field data in the file i'am working on have spaces and carriage returns - Not sure how to capture this fields

Comment: `$contentfile = (get-content "c:\citi2.txt")` # reading the input `for ($i=1; $i -le ($contentfile.count -1);$i++)` /*getting the count excluding the header*/ `{ $extractfield = $contentfile[$i].split(",")` /*splitting it by comma*/ `print $extractfield[12]}` /*trying to print field No 12*/

Comment: Seems like a lot of work when PS has CSV handling baked in

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input that you provided, if you had a file named foo.txt, then:

```
Import-CSV C:\Path\To\foo.txt -Header (1..25) | Select-Object '4', '6', '8'
```

Would give you the 4th, 6th, and 8th fields. You could of course use much more descriptive headers and if the file had headers in the first row you could use those without specifying your own.

Comment: Thanks Much EBGreen!! that worked. i see the fieldnumber and the header name followed by data. what if i just wanted the data itself without the rest of the two?

Comment: Then you could slap a | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders on the end.

Comment: Generally speaking you want to avoid Format-Table as long as possible in the pipe though since it recasts the objects to strings which makes them much less versatile.

Comment: format-table -HideTableHeaders cmdlet cuts off the first field which in my case is '14', but i'am trying to pull out the second field name coming from the file. i'am trying to see if i can strip off the two lines (two headers '14' , 'Account No') and make sure there are no empty lines left for those two headers, do we have any cmdlet that suffice this requirement?

Comment: 'Account NO' and '14' do not appear anywhere in the sample that you gave. Without an accurate sample and an accurate description of exactly what you want, it is really hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: sorry about that, below is what it looks like when i issue the command `Import-CSV C:\citi\citi2.txt -Header (1..25) | Select-Object '14'` the output i'am getting is `14 Bene or Debit Party Acct Number XXXAAAA6 ABCXXXXXXXX10100ZZZZZZ02000 xxxxxx600053xxxxxx XXXX42BARC2XXXXXX` i dont need the first two lines '14' and 'bene or debit party' and i dont want the empty lines after they are stripped off

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13748/discussion-between-user1411254-and-ebgreen)

Comment: Well I would, but I'm a little busy here at work. To be honest with you, right now your issue is very specific to your data.